# C++ Text Editor Flickering

Tags: c++, string, text, editor

I'm writing this matrix text editor in C++, as the keyboard iterates through the string it flickers. I've tried encapsulating displaytravel(); into a Row class member, but no improvements. Am I better off doing this in C, and creating my own string structure?

```
void cursor(string input)
{

char a;
int index=0;
string use = "";
string bfr,aftr;

string::iterator itr = input.begin();
cout<<input<<endl;
    do
    {
        a=getch();
        if(a==77)
        {
       ///Right
        index++;
        itr++;
        displaytravel(input, index, itr);
        }
        else if(a==75)
        {
        ///Left
        index--;
        itr--;
        displaytravel(input, index, itr);
        }

    }while(a!=27);
}

void displaytravel(string input, int index, string::iterator itr)
{
    string bfr = input;
    string aftr = input;

    bfr.erase(bfr.begin()+index,bfr.end());
    aftr.erase(0,index+1);
    system("cls");
   cout<<bfr<<*itr<<"|"<<aftr<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Off topic: you should really guard the ends of the string. Very easy at the moment to march out of bounds.

Comment: What do you mean by guard end of the string?

Comment: The use of `system("cls");` is a brutal hammer and probably the source of most of your pain. You may have better luck with conio's `clrscr()` function, but you don't really want to clear the screen. You want to swap the | and one character on the screen, not redraw everything. I have no clue how to do that with conio.

Comment: Guarding the ends of the string: Say the firth thing the user does is hit the left arrow. `index` goes negative, `itr` moves to one before the string starts and very bad things will happen when you try to use either of them. You need to test if hitting the arrow will place the cursor out of bounds before trying to redraw the string.

Comment: Out of bounds, as in the beginning and end of the string? This whole string is a line.

Comment: Yes. Out of bounds as in before the beginning or after the end.

Comment: Thank you, should less iterators be used for less complexity?

Comment: Used correctly, iterators reduce complexity, but in this case I would dereference the iterator at the function call and pass in the referenced `char`.

Comment: So, I've added a string guard along with a char swap for the travel function. I've switched to MSDN's window.h ClearScreen(), but the flickering remains. Do you know of a still supported library that deals with Screen clearing>
`void displaytravel(string input, int index)
{
        string n = "|";
        swap(input[index],n[0]);

        cout<<input<<" "<<index;
}`

Comment: The flicker is because it takes time to render and draw stuff on the screen. If you clear the screen and then redraw, this give you a window to see the empty screen before the new screen is drawn. But if instead of redrawing the entire screen you draw over the little rectangle that bounds the two characters that need to change (Keyword: Dirty Rectangle) no one is likely to see the change. What you need is a library that allows you to just change the two characters that need changing without having to clear and redraw everything.